# Aws Lambda with terraform, invalid source_code_hash

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I have terraform that deploys aws lambda go project, build #1:

```
 # module.api_cloneChallenge.aws_lambda_function.api_service will be updated in-place
  ~ resource "aws_lambda_function" "api_service" {
        id                             = "gs-dev-api-cloneChallenge"
      ~ last_modified                  = "2023-05-18T07:56:00.000+0000" -> (known after apply)
      ~ source_code_hash               = "hjmfsj2XzbEKUUIlEm/Qs9DnjOVbEaIngtySBVVZ/qk=" -> "dn01BTEl9sqcIWsXGaa0FBxworrCawR9cDnpcSNcUyo="
        tags                           = {
            "Layer"       = "API"
            "Name"        = "gs-dev-api-cloneChallenge"
            "OperationID" = "cloneChallenge"
            "Stage"       = "dev"
        }
        # (16 unchanged attributes hidden)

        # (2 unchanged blocks hidden)
    }
```

shows me that current new hash will be "dn01BTEl9sqcIWsXGaa0FBxworrCawR9cDnpcSNcUyo="
but on next build:

```
# module.api_cloneChallenge.aws_lambda_function.api_service will be updated in-place
  ~ resource "aws_lambda_function" "api_service" {
        id                             = "gs-dev-api-cloneChallenge"
      ~ last_modified                  = "2023-05-18T08:25:48.000+0000" -> (known after apply)
      ~ source_code_hash               = "xgzR2ARivgWErotmKxpRdCEptOYZGTtevVvyQV8Gbbs=" -> "k1s1s3QgzyZhLn1vvKxszs3N5bII5eR8WKt2N4grgIQ="
        tags                           = {
            "Layer"       = "API"
            "Name"        = "gs-dev-api-cloneChallenge"
            "OperationID" = "cloneChallenge"
            "Stage"       = "dev"
        }
        # (16 unchanged attributes hidden)

        # (2 unchanged blocks hidden)
    }
```

is see totally different previous value, why ?
probably important:

```
value = filebase64sha256(data.external.makefile_package.result.binary_path)
```

in terraform I count sha256 of binary file not zip, because zip even if using deterministic-zip its different on each github actions build :(
btw I also tried using last commit hash that modified the file, and the same issue, terraform was logging what it will save now but after deployment when I downlloaded tfstate file source_code_hash was totally different value.Looks like its saving there some different value and I dont know why..

What I see is that source_code_hash is always the same value what is in SHA256 hash in aws. Why ? I can not put there some custom value ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the remote API supports it, Terraform providers will typically read the latest values from the remote API before planning. The Lambda API knows the hash of your `.zip` file and returns it to the Terraform AWS provider, and so the AWS provider then detects that your executable file does not match that checksum and so proposes to replace it.

For this to work as intended you must calculate your checksum the same way that the remote API does, which I believe means you must use the checksum of the `.zip` file. As you noted, it can be challenging to reproduce an identical `.zip` file because these files include metadata such as the last modified timestamps of files, which will vary each time you rebuild the files.

If you are creating your `.zip` files using the typical Unix tool `zip` then you might try using its `--no-extra` option to disable saving most of the metadata associated with your files. I've not confirmed whether that removes the last modified times in particular, but based on my knowledge of the zip file format I suspect that it will.

If you change your build process to always produce identical zip files as long as the files inside have not changed then you'll be able to use the hash of your zip file as `source_code_hash` and so it should then match what AWS lambda reports as the current checksum, and so the provider will not think that your file has changed.

Comment: One could put the hash in the zip file name and not use the source code hash but the file name to detect changes.